# данны пары значений и нужно сложить каждую пару

Tags: c++

задача звучит как "Входные данные содержат в первой строке N - общее количество пар, которые нужно посчитать.
Последующие N строк содержат по одной паре целых чисел каждая.
Ответ должен содержать результаты, разделенные пробелами."
Данные:
13
993508 552681
764213 755753
758919 737063
801448 13151
861932 856219
755723 134094
96700 187858
855652 98052
242036 649672
978264 108233
352948 799350
659120 388171
107107 966704
Я сделал как сложить все значения массива в один результат, но как сложить только пары из массива?

код:
#include 
using namespace std;

```
int main()
{
    const int nMax = 50;
    int arr[nMax];
    int n;
    int sum = 0;

    cin >> n;

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> arr[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        sum += arr[i];
    }
    cout << sum;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: отредактировалл

Comment: Ну, если так хочется помучиться - просто используйте цикл `for(int i = 0; i < n; i+=2) cout << arr[i] + arr[i+1] << ' ';`

Comment: у меня int n - это количество складываемых значений, которое осталось из предыдущей задачи, но теперь мне дают пары, и мне нужно указывать именно их. Как можно это переделать, чтобы я писал колиство пар, а не отдельных значений, если так и оставлять то мне нужно писать в два раза больше значение, те если дано 5 пар, то я пишу 10 и это мне не совсем нравится. И по поводу циклу, почему у условях фор i+=2? и в сложении написано + arr[i+1] - что это значит? типа если i=10 то 10+1? или i+следующее число из массива?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам не нужен массив, и складывать всё вместе тоже ни к чему - вопрос-то ведь о суммах пар.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream> 

int main()
{
    int a, b, n;
    std::stringstream res;
    std::cin >> n;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        std::cin >> a >> b;
        res << a + b << " ";
    }
    std::cout << res.str();
}
```

Вроде всё.

Comment: почему не нужен? проще же будет ввести все пары, чем вводить каждый раз по два числа

Comment: ЗАЧЕМ??? Их же не нужно хранить для дальнейшего использования - вот и не плодите сущности сверх необходимого. Задана задача вывести суммы пар - решаем именно эту задачу, а про массив ничего не говорится.

Comment: в предыдущем задании было сказанно, чтобы сделать программу читающую числа вручную, а эта задача та же самая, только нужно сложить пары. Писать каждое число займет много времени, + нужно получить ответ сразу разделенный пробелами

Comment: Приведите точное условие задачи. Полный код для задачи "сложить числа в парах и вывести суммы через пробел" приведён.

Comment: В предыдущей задачи дополнительно написано: "тк чисел много, нужно сделать программу читающую данные с ввода в коносль, куда я могу скопировать нужные мне значения". В этой задачи приведен пример как у меня должно получиться data:
  3 (количество вообщем пар)
   {100 8}
   {15 245}
   {1945 54} - в скобках пары, тк я не знаю как здесь написать на другой строке

   answer:
   108 260 1999

Comment: я пытался сделать чтобы каждое число из массива нумеровалась индексом 0 и 1, чтобы в цикле просто сложить пронумерованные индексом 0 и 1 числа, но не могу понять как это сделать

Comment: у меня в visual studio подругом выводит https://prnt.sc/13k15pf

Comment: OK, я понял, в чём дело. Изменил

Comment: @ADOLF ABOOOBA Задача решена?

Comment: да, спасибо @MBo